# python packaging to support various major interpreters

Tags: python

I have an open source project that works fine with python 2 and I am trying to make it work on python 3 as well.
I tried one approach that is using if statements in the code to check `sys.version_info.major` but this seems to be messy.
Is it possible to specify the interpreter version in setup.py to that when folks use pip install, it automatically pick up a compatible package?

This way, I can branch the code and the packages on github.
so lets say I have

```
x1.2 for python < 3
x1.1 for python >= 3
```

if the user has python3, pip should grab x1.1 (not the latest but the latest package for python3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for you to specify what version `pip` should install, no. You can specify Python compatibility in the Trove classifiers, but `pip` will not differentiate on those, let alone pick a different version based on that.

You are stuck with writing a version that works on both Python 2 and 3. I recommend you read through the [*Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3* guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) and use a compatibility layer support library like [`six`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six). You can use the [Modernize tool](http://python-modernize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to help you rewrite your code here.

Comment: Thanks all. This is a major flaw of pip then. I actually managed to port things manually but now I know there are easier ways. The only problem is that the code is starting to look ugly due to changes in packages names which forces me to put conditions. I think one other approach might be to make a duplicate project with a "3" added to the project/package name in case someone else might be interested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) :

> 2to3 is a Python program that reads Python 2.x source code and applies a series of fixers to transform it into valid Python 3.x code.

and as @Martijn says in comment you can find the best recipe in [`Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html)

Comment: `2to3` is no magic bullet that makes any project work on 3.x. You still need to put in some work for this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i think its depends on the OP's code ! is it so ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying.

Comment: Note that `2to3` is listed under the *dropping Python 2 support completely* option. I *think* there are ways to use `lib2to3` from setuptools but it is not recommended.